# iPad Custom Font

Tags: iphone, ipad

is there a way to load an own Font with the iPad SDK? I cannot find a useful example of what file-type the font has to be or how the LIB of the iPad is called.

Can you provide further informations?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

[Here is a very simple description what you have to do](http://doli.at/2010/05/08/custom-fonts-ipad/).

Comment: link has a redirect loop

Answer (score 4):

UIAppFonts (Array - iPhone OS) specifies any application-provided fonts that should be made available through the normal mechanisms. Each item in the array is a string containing the name of a font file (including filename extension) that is located in the application’s bundle. The system loads the specified fonts and makes them available for use by the application when that application is run.

http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/General/Reference/InfoPlistKeyReference/Articles/iPhoneOSKeys.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40009252-SW18

Ahead is a note from [iPad Human Interface Guidelines](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/General/Conceptual/iPadHIG/index.html)

Note that fonts of type .ttf or .otf work on iPad; traditional Mac OS fonts (that is, Classic font suitcases) do not work on iPad.